# changing a parent font from an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an iframe which is from a third party live chat provider (Tidio chat) and I want to change the font of all texts inside:

Here is a code I'm using and it works fine:

```
document.getElementById("tidio-chat-iframe").contentDocument.body.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
```

The problem is I want to use my own fonts which is located and accessible from parent so I used this one instead:

```
document.getElementById("tidio-chat-iframe").contentDocument.body.style.fontFamily = "Lalezar";
```

but as the iframe page doesn't inherit any CSS from the parent page I need to include the style sheet for the font in the iframe page also.

the issue is when we use a third party iframe which is included in our page via an script we can't do that...

I mean If I myself created that iframe I could import the font into it apparently but now ...

How can I use a parent font from an iframe using javascript?

Please do not flag this question as duplicate ... there is no similar question on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet is an example of how can a parent inject/change css of an iframe.

```
window.onload = function() {
   let myiFrame = document.getElementById("myiFrame");
   let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>/******* Put your styles here *******</style>';
}
```

adding css to a iframe

```
window.onload = function() {
  let link = document.createElement("link");
  link.href = "style.css";      /**** your CSS file ****/ 
  link.rel = "stylesheet"; 
  link.type = "text/css"; 
  frames[0].document.head.appendChild(link); /**** 0 is an index of your iframe ****/ 
}
```

please refer - https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/

Comment: We can change the style simply but the iframe does not have access to the parent font so it wouldn't work

Comment: please refer https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/

Comment: This inject the style properly but distortion occures why? `doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>@font-face {font-family: IRANSansWeb;src: url(fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff) format("woff")}</style>';`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work:

> Copy below code in to your custom js
> **Make sure you use jQuery**.

> **You must replace your values in [[ ]] and remove the brackets**

```
(($) => {
      $(document).ready(() => {
         const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations_list) {
            mutations_list.forEach(function (mutation) {
              mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function (added_node) {
                const $iframeCheck = $("[[ Id iframe tidio]]");
                if ($iframeCheck.length) {
                  const style = `
                  @font-face {
                    font-family:'[[IRANSansWeb]]';
                    src: url("[[./wp-content/fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff]]") format("woff2")
                        
                  }
                    body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,button, input, select, 
                    textarea { font-family: '[[IRANSansWeb]]' !important; }
                  `;
                  let $styleTag = $(
                    `<style id='style_custom' type="text/css">${style}</style>`
                  );
                  $iframeCheck.contents().find("head").append($styleTag);
    
                  observer.disconnect();
                }
              });
            });
          });
          observer.observe($("body")[0], { subtree: true, childList: true });
        };
      });
    })(jQuery);
```